# Shared Element Return transition flickering on view visibility changed

Tags: android, kotlin, shared-element-transition

Shared element enter transition works fine. After 5 seconds of enter transition, the shared element(ImageView) is set to gone. I change its visibility in finishAfterTransition from gone to visible. But the transition is not smooth.

```
override fun finishAfterTransition() {
    videoThumb.visibility = VISIBLE
    val data = Intent()
    data.putExtra(ActivityTag, VideoActivityTag)
    data.putExtra(StartPosition, mappedPosition)
    data.putExtra(CurrentPosition, currentPosition)
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data)
    super.finishAfterTransition()
}
```